# How to prove associative law for groups

Tags: proof-writing, associativity

I'm having trouble figuring out the proof to the proposition: for any $a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n \in \mathbb{G}$ the value of $a_1~R~a_2~R~a_3~R\cdots R~a_n$ is independent of how the expression is bracketed (this is called the generalized associative law).

If $R$ was an equivalence relation this would be quite easy by using the symmetry of the relation to show commutativity and associativity.

I don't really know which definitions/assumptions to start with to prove this. I want to prove this locally for a few elements first and then by induction extend that to all elements in $G$. How may I do this?

Comment: Um, what is R?  the implication is it is a relation.  But what does a R b R c mean?  a R b means (a,b) $\in$ R $\subset G \times G$ but that's a statement; not a group element.  I have no idea how a R {(a,b) $\in $ R} is supposed to be interpreted.

Comment: @fleablood a R b R c is like a * b * c. It's just a relation how else can you interpret it?

Comment: In a . b "." is a binary operation so (a.b).c  and a.(b.c) makes perfect sense.  (a.b)  and (b.c) are elements so a.(b.c) and (a.b).c are operations on two elements one of which is itself is the result of the operation on two elements.  But a R b is *not* an element but a statement that a and b are related.  In which case a R b R c makes no sense whatsoever.  Let b R c mean "b is taller than c".  So a R (b R c) means "a is taller than the statement that b is taller than c".  That does **not** make any sense and can not be interpreted in *any* way possible.

Comment: I think the only way it can actually make any sense is to absolutely *abuse* the notation and semantics and to mistakenly make it to mean a R b while at the same time b R c.  But then a R (b R c) doesn't actually mean anything and saying (a R b) R c = a R (b R c) is ... meaningless.  Anyway I am serious.  What sense does a R b R c mean.  a R b means $(a,b) \in R$ so a R b R c means "(a, {$(b,c) \in R$})$ \in R$ which is  gibberish.

Comment: If G is the set of integers and * is + then a + b is an integer.  If a R b is "a divides b" then "a R b" is *not* itself an integer.  What is it?  It is a statement.  So what is "a R statement"?  How is that to be interpreted? What is "27 divides '2 divides 10'"?

Comment: Oh I was treating the binary operation as a relation on accident. I am surprised no one pointed that out earlier. operation != relation so yes what you're saying is true it doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The induction starts with three elements - that's just the associativity axiom!

If we have $n$ elements, $a_1, \ldots, a_n$, then we either have $a_1 (a_2   \ldots a_n)$ or $(a_1 \ldots a_{n-1}) a_n$. Notice that inside the bracket we have $n-1$ elements, so by induction, it doesn't matter how we bracket them.

In particular, for the first case we can choose the bracketing to be $a_1 ((a_2 a_3) \ldots a_n)$, which is the same as $(a_1 ((a_2 a_3) \ldots a_{n-1}))a_n$. Again, we have $n-1$ elements in the left-hand bracket so it doesn't matter how we bracket them, so this is the same as $(a_1 \ldots a_{n-1})a_n$.

So all expressions of the second form are equal to each other, and all expressions of the first form are equal to an expression of the second form. Therefore it doesn't matter where you put the brackets!

**Edit:** as pointed out in the comments, I had missed an important case. We might have $(a_1 \ldots a_r) (a_{r+1} \ldots a_n)$. However, this can be dealt with in the same way: both of these brackets have fewer than $n$ elements, so it doesn't matter how we bracket inside them. In particular, it's the same as $(a_1 (a_2 \ldots a_r)) (a_{r+1} \ldots a_n)$, which is the same as $a_1 ((a_2 \ldots a_r)(a_{r+1} \ldots a_n))$, which is the same as $a_1 (a_2 \ldots a_n)$ by the induction hypothesis. Therefore bracketings of this new form agree with the two cases previously considered.

Comment: Is it okay to start with the associativity axiom? I'm not sure if it was. If you didn't how would one prove the associativity for, say, three elements?

Comment: Actually it makes sense to use that axiom since above that it states : If G is a group under the operation R, then.. so yeah that makes sense.

Comment: You can't prove the 3-element associativity axiom from the other axioms for a group! (Which is exactly why it's necessary to include it as an axiom.) So it's definitely reasonable to assume it.

The point of your question is t answer the question "why do we only ask for the 3-element associativity law rather than the generalised associativity law?"

Comment: Um, if R is a group operation, what is there to prove?  That's part of the definition of a group!

Comment: No, the 3-element associativity axiom is part of the group definition. That is, it is an axiom that $(ab)c = a(bc)$. It's not an axiom that e.g. $(ab)(cd) = (a(bc))d$, and the OP's question was asking you to show that all of these "generalised" associativity relations follow from the 3-element associativity relation.

Comment: Dear @JoshHunt, if $n=4$, then we could have $(a_1 a_2)(a_3 a_4)$, which doesn't take either of the (two) forms of bracketization you wrote. In other words, it doesn't have a single "outermost element" either to the left or to the right. Does this invalidate the proof?

Comment: You are correct, I either missed a case or was very sloppy when writing up! Thankfully the same proof goes through, I'll add it to my answer. Thanks!